# Adding mysql query to this email function

Tags: php, function, email

I have the below function in my registration process that will send and email out to users upon completion of the registration process.  I would like the text of the email to be different depending on what type of user they are. I have business users and personal users and its identified in the database as 1 or 0.  This is what I have so far.

```
 function SendBusWelcomeEmail(&$user_rec)
    {
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT business FROM users")
               or die(mysql_error());

                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {

            $actiontype = $row['business'];
            switch ($actiontype)
{
case "0":
        $mailer = new PHPMailer();

        $mailer->CharSet = 'utf-8';

        $mailer->AddAddress($user_rec['email'],$user_rec['name']);

        $mailer->Subject = "Welcome to ".$this->sitename;

        $mailer->From = $this->GetFromAddress();        

        $mailer->Body ="Hello ".$user_rec['name']."\r\n\r\n".
        "Welcome! Your registration  with ".$this->sitename." is completed.\r\n".
        "\r\n".
        "Regards,\r\n".
        "Webmaster\r\n".
        $this->sitename;

        if(!$mailer->Send())
        {
            $this->HandleError("Failed sending user welcome email.");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
break;
case "1":
  $mailer = new PHPMailer();

        $mailer->CharSet = 'utf-8';

        $mailer->AddAddress($user_rec['email'],$user_rec['name']);

        $mailer->Subject = "Welcome to ".$this->sitename;

        $mailer->From = $this->GetFromAddress();        

        $mailer->Body ="Hello ".$user_rec['name']."\r\n\r\n".
        "Welcome! thanks for your business etc etc with ".$this->sitename." is completed.\r\n".
        "\r\n".
        "Regards,\r\n".
        "Webmaster\r\n".
        $this->sitename;

        if(!$mailer->Send())
        {
            $this->HandleError("Failed sending user welcome email.");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Is there a questions coming?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: the question is that I would like to send different emails based on the user type, business or personal.  Is this the right approach?

Comment: @Steven: You can probably take some of the duplicated code and put it before the *switch*, then put the `$mailer->Send()` after the `switch`.

Comment: agree with Rocket. it will minimize bugs. other than that, don't use mysql_query since its deprecated. try mysqli calls instead.

Comment: @RocketHazmat how can I do that if I want the text of the message to be different depending on the case?

Comment: @Steven: `switch` statements don't introduce a new scope.  Just set the variables inside, then use then afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps.

```
function SendBusWelcomeEmail(&$user_rec)
{
    $mailer = new PHPMailer();
    $mailer->CharSet = 'utf-8';
    $mailer->AddAddress($user_rec['email'], $user_rec['name']);
    $mailer->Subject = "Welcome to ".$this->sitename;
    $mailer->From = $this->GetFromAddress();        

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT business FROM users") or die(mysql_error());
    if (mysql_num_rows($result))
    {
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

        $actiontype = $row['business'];
        switch ($actiontype)
        {
            case "0":
                $mailer->Body = "Hello ".$user_rec['name']."\r\n\r\n"."Welcome! Your registration  with ".$this->sitename." is completed.\r\n"."\r\n"."Regards,\r\n"."Webmaster\r\n".$this->sitename;
                break;

            case "1":
                $mailer->Body = "Hello ".$user_rec['name']."\r\n\r\n"."Welcome! thanks for your business etc etc with ".$this->sitename." is completed.\r\n"."\r\n"."Regards,\r\n"."Webmaster\r\n".$this->sitename;
                break;
        }

        if (!$mailer->Send())
        {
            $this->HandleError("Failed sending user welcome email.");
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

I'm assuming the query should include some kind of where clause so that you're not querying the entire users table every time. I removed the `while` loop since you were returning after sending the e-mail anyway.